# Postfix "loops back to myself" only when trying to send to fallback relay

Tags: postfix

I have read the many answers to many similar questions, but have not found exactly this question or any answer that helped.

I have a Postfix 2.11 server (`mail-server.example.com`) that is strictly for outgoing email. It works fine if it is able to send the email on the first try. However, for performance reasons, if it cannot send the email on the first try and instead wants to defer it, I have configured `smtp_fallback_relay` so that it forwards the email to another server (`deferred-mail.example.com`) that handles only deferred emails.

```
smtp_fallback_relay = [deferred-mail.example.com]
```

If, from my trusted IP (`mynetworks`), I send an email to either server destined for `someone@gmail.com`, either server will accept it and try to send it to Gmail. Because my server IP is new, Gmail rejects the email from either server with `421` (temporary deferral). As expected, the `deferred-mail` server simply puts the message in its deferred queue and tries again later.

The weird part is that while `mail-server` will send the message to Gmail to begin with, after receiving the `421`, it attempts to send the mail to `deferred-mail`, but gives up and instead bounces the message, saying "mail for gmail.com loops back to myself". I see no logs on the `deferred-mail` server saying anything about what is going on.

So both servers are configured to accept mail and relay it to Gmail if the client is trusted, and the `deferred-mail` trusts `mail-server` (I can send to a Gmail address when directly connecting to `deferred-mail` from `mail-server), so how is Postfix coming up with this "loop" and why is it bouncing the email instead of relaying it?

---

**Update and clarification** about the logs below.

For privacy reasons, I am not posting the actual domain name or IP addresses we are using. Throughout this post and in the log excerpt below, I have replaced the actual root domain name we are using with `example.com`.

This setup was copied from a working email cluster. I am confident that it is theoretically sound, and suspect it is just a matter of some setting not being correctly replaced or translated. It is just that with this odd behavior and seemingly incorrect error message, I cannot figure out what to change, and that is why I am asking for help.

- **"Greeted me with my own hostname" is not a mistake or problem**

When sending emails via SMTP, the sender begins by identifying itself by host name. Big mail processors like Gmail and Yahoo take several steps to assess the reputation of the sender. With IPv4, two of the first things they did were

1. Record the IP address of the sender and build up a record of the quality and quantity of emails coming from that specific IP address
2. Verify that the [reverse DNS record](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/glossary/reverse-dns/) for that IP address maps back to the host name the sender identified itself with

If the IP address has a bad reputation or the reverse DNS does not match the sender host name, the receiver would be much more likely to mark the email as Spam regardless of anything else.

For both these reasons, both `mail-server.example.com` and `deferred-mail.example.com` are behind the same NAT Gateway that

1. Has a static IP address, so all email comes from the same IP address with the same reputation (`REDACTED-PUBLIC-IPv4` in the log excerpt below)
2. Has a reverse DNS record that identifies that IP address as `mail-server.example.com`

For that reason, when `deferred-mail.example.com` identifies itself in an SMTP session, it identifies itself as `mail-server.example.com`. This is correct, desired behavior and not an uncommon situation for the reasons stated above. (`deferred-mail.example.com` points to a private IP address, `10.111.14.181` in the logs below and does not have a reverse DNS record.)

- **IPv6 failure is not a mistake or problem**

Our server stack does not currently have IPv6 enabled. Because we are using a new domain name, we have zero domain reputation, so we want to stick to IP reputation until we have a solid domain reputation established. (Because IPv6 addresses are disposable, they will never be an adequate basis for reputation.)

Therefore, the failures to reach Gmail's IPv6 servers `aspmx.l.google.com` and `alt2.aspmx.l.google.com` are expected and not particularly a problem, although if there is a setting that I can set to keep `postfix` from even trying to reach IPv6 addresses, please let me know so I can make that change.

*Answer to disabling IPv6 attempts:* Add this to your `main.cf`

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

---

#### Per request, here are redacted logs of the error:

```
postfix/smtpd[26668]: 50F7C5B81: client=ip-10-111-7-75.us-west-2.compute.internal[10.111.7.75]
postfix/cleanup[26682]: 50F7C5B81: message-id=<>
opendkim[36]: 50F7C5B81: can't determine message sender; accepting
postfix/qmgr[143]: 50F7C5B81: from=<REDACTED-SENDER>, size=279, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtp[26686]: 50F7C5B81: host aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.197.26] said: 421-4.7.0 [REDACTED-PUBLIC-IPv4      15] Our system has detected that this message is 421-4.7.0 suspicious ... 
postfix/smtp[26686]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c07::1a]:25: Cannot assign requested address
postfix/smtp[26686]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c56::1a]:25: Cannot assign requested address
postfix/smtp[26686]: 50F7C5B81: host alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[142.250.152.27] said: 421-4.7.0 [REDACTED-PUBLIC-IPv4      15] Our system has detected that this message is 421-4.7.0 suspicious ...
postfix/smtp[26686]: warning: host deferred-mail.example.com[10.111.14.181]:25 greeted me with my own hostname mail-server.example.com
postfix/smtp[26686]: warning: host deferred-mail.example.com[10.111.14.181]:25 replied to HELO/EHLO with my own hostname mail-server.example.com
postfix/smtp[26686]: 50F7C5B81: to=<someone@gmail.com>, relay=deferred-mail.example.com[10.111.14.181]:25, delay=26, delays=24/0.01/1.5/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for gmail.com loops back to myself)

log messages here about sending bounce email to sender
have been removed 

postfix/bounce[26688]: 50F7C5B81: sender non-delivery notification: AEA8A5B83
postfix/qmgr[143]: 50F7C5B81: removed
```

Comment: Could you add the logs of the error, please ?

Comment: @Dom logs added. There are no corresponding log entries on the relay server. To keep the log spam down we are filtering out connect/disconnect log messages.

Comment: Sounds like your IPv6 is broken *and* on top of that either your DNS for `deferred-mail` is broken and you indeed connect to yourself.. or that mail server does not know its own host name.

Comment: @anx Per your request, I have updated the post with information about our setup and the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Do higher log levels (`smtpd -v`) spell out the actual record that made Postfix claim looping?

Comment: @anx No, higher log levels do not reveal anything between fallback_relay `replied to HELO/EHLO with my own hostname` and the start of bounce processing. I can believe that getting its own hostname is triggering some kind of loop filter, but (a) I know other systems are doing the same thing successfully and (b) I would not expect the error message to be that `gmail.com loops to myself`, I would expect an error message about the fallback relay.

Answer (score 1):

According to a post I found in a forum somewhere, using any port other than port 25 will disable the mail loop detection that I was running into. However, I have been unable to find any authoritative source for either why the mail was considered looping or why changing the connection port made a difference. I will leave this question open for an answer that points to authoritative sources.

The solution that worked for me was to add TLS certificates and enable SMTP and TLS on port 587 on `deferred-mail.example.com` and change the configuration on `mail-server.example.com` to

```
smtp_fallback_relay = [deferred-mail.example.com]:587
```

I think this is more than is necessary; the post said any port other than 25 would do. I did it this way because I wanted to correctly set up TLS on port 587 anyway.

Answer (score -1):

A loop is detected because the destination server is replying with the hostname that sending server is configured with. It *is* that simple.

The code is a bit convoluted, but a convincing section (note the two different error messages for the same actual condition) is https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/2595917e491dfe704390b9bf1100bcdd35b21ae8/postfix/src/smtp/smtp_proto.c#L548-L563

To avoid this problem I recommend re-examining the reasons that are pushing you to use the same hostname on both your hosts. Maybe they don't really need to be the same? Maybe just the hostname as used by postfix could be different? Maybe you can configure a secondary listener on the second host that has a different hostname (another port)? Maybe you can disable the warning, but that can be dangerous since you are modifying things; the next modification could be an unexpected loop that would not be caught.

Comment: See the "Greeted me with my own hostname is not a mistake or problem" section of the post for the reasoning to use the same hostname. The code you referenced seems more like a bug than a feature, since by comment it seems to be related to TLS Session Cache management and since it only applies when the destination port is 25. There is no good explanation for the behavior in the comments of the code you referenced.

Comment: As I said, it's a bit convoluted, I have ignored anything related to TLS Session cache. However, only applying when the port is 25 is perfectly in line with what I'm saying. You problem goes away when you are sending to another port. It's not a bug, it's a protection against loops, and you are falling foul of it.